# Parallel array assignment in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variable-assignment

Most languages make it easy to take an array like `[1, 2, 3]` and assign those values to variables `a`, `b`, and `c` with a single command.
For example, in Perl you can do

```
($a, $b, $c) = (1, 2, 3);
```

What's the corresponding trick in PHP?

[Thanks so much for the lightning fast answer!  I know this is a trivial question but all the obvious google queries didn't turn up the answer so this is my attempt to fix that.]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`list()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($a, $b, $c) = $someArray;
```

Comment: Ha, figures PHP has an entire language construct, complete with a special reserved word, for this.  Thanks, btw!

Answer (score 12):

Use [list](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_list.asp)

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
list($a, $b, $c) = $arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 7.1 you can use the list shorthand `[]` for array destructuring.

```
[$a, $b, $c] = [1, 2, 3];
```

Also as of 7.1 you can destructure non-numerically keyed arrays similar to the way that object destructuring works in ES6. https://stitcher.io/blog/array-destructuring-with-list-in-php