# php array regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I am using regular expressions in php to match postcodes found in a string.

The results are being returned as an array, I was wondering if there is any way to assign variables to each of the results, something like

```
$postcode1 = first match found
$postcode2 = second match found
```

here is my code

```
$html = "some text here bt123ab and another postcode bt112cd";
preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z]{2})([0-9]{2,3})([a-zA-Z]{2})/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo $val[0]; }
```

I am very new to regular expressions and php, forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to assign the contents of an array to variables? If yes, you can use the `list()` function (http://ch2.php.net/list).

Comment: Smart to use `list()` but I think the trickier part is getting the postcodes into a simple array in the first place. $matches is a multidimensional array and you need to pick the zeroth element from each of its sub-arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** In order to make this example work, you have to use `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` instead of `PREG_SET_ORDER` (I thought you used it in your code, but obviously I read too fast ;)):

> `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`
>   Orders results so that `$matches[0]` is an array of **full pattern matches**, `$matches[1]` is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

If you really want to, you can assign them to variables:

```
$postcode1 = $matches[0][0];
$postcode2 = $matches[0][1];
```

But it is easier to just access the array elements imo.

Or something more fancy:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        ${'postcode'.$i+1} = $matches[0][$i];
}
```

---

But I would just do:

```
$postcodes = $matches[0];
```

and then access the postcodes via normal array access.

Comment: $matches[0] is actually not the array of postcodes though!  You need to get the zeroth element of each member of $matches.

Comment: @dreeves: You are right, I thought the OP used `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` in his code. Actually with this flag it is much easier to get the all postcodes.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for PHP 5.3+:

```
$postcodearray = array_map(function($x) {return $x[0];}, $matches);
list($postcode1, $postcode2) = $postcodearray;
```

(Which of course could be combined into one line if you don't care about the array of postcodes itself.)
To get the array of postcodes it uses an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).
For the `list()` construct, see this related question:  [Parallel array assignment in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182563/parallel-array-assignment-in-php)

If you don't have PHP 5.3+ (or if that anonymous function is confusing) you can define a function "first" like so

```
function first($x) { return $x[0]; }
```

and then get the array of postcodes like so:

```
array_map("first", $matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($matches as $index => $val) {
    $prefix ='postcode'.$index;
    ${$prefix} = $val;
}
```