# Parallel list assignment in Red language

Tags: list, variable-assignment, rebol, red

I have 2 lists:

```
alist: [a b c d]
blist: [1 2 3 4]
```

(In reality they are long lists). How can I assign variables in alist to corresponding values in blist in one go? Hence a becomes 1, b becomes 2 and so on.

I tried:

```
foreach i alist j blist [i: j]
```

But it give following error:

```
*** Script Error: j has no value
*** Where: foreach
*** Stack:
```

I also tried:

```
i: 1
while [true] [ 
    if i > (length? alist) [break]
    alist/i: blist/i  
    i: i + 1
]
```

But it also does not work:

```
*** Script Error: cannot set none in path alist/i:
*** Where: set-path
*** Stack:
```

`alist/i` and `blist/i` return `none` (on checking with print command).

Similar question are there for other languages also, e.g.: [Parallel array assignment in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182563/parallel-array-assignment-in-php) and [Parallel assignment in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917684/parallel-assignment-in-java) . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easy way, set one list to the other

```
>> set alist blist
== [1 2 3 4]
>> a
== 1
>> b
== 2
>> c
== 3
>> d
== 4
>> alist
== [a b c d]
>> reduce alist
== [1 2 3 4]
>> get alist/1    
== 1
```

and the cumbersome way

```
>> forall alist [alist/1: blist/(index? alist) ]
>> i: 2
== 2
>> get alist/:i
== 2
```

Comment: If i=1, how can I get a list/i ?

Comment: Also how can I get a list with series of numbers, like 1:10 maybe step 2?

Comment: Is there a map function also in red to apply a function to all elements of list?

Comment: have a look at >>help map-each and >>help for

Comment: @mso you do know about https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol ?

Comment: Red does not have an official map-each, but sooner than later it will come. Until then there are some implementations done by users you can search on gitter.im/red/red. Same situation with for. Ask for help on gitter.im/red/help

Comment: Is `pick alist i` same as `alist/:i`?  Similarly, are `poke alist i 5`  and `alist/:i: 5` also same?

Comment: Is pick alist i same as alist/:i? Yes and no. If i is integer yes, otherwise alist/:i like select alist i. a.s.o. No to the second question