# Why variables not altering from a loop in Red language

Tags: list, variable-assignment, rebol, red

I want to alter a series of variables from a loop, but the following code is not working:

```
a: 10
b: 20
c: 30
print reduce [a b c]              ; output is 10 20 30 as expected

varnames: [a b c]                 ; make a series of variables
foreach i varnames [              ; loop to convert each to 0
    i: 0
]

print "After conversion loop: "
print reduce [a b c]              ; values are still 10 20 30 (expected 0 0 0)
```

After running this code, I'd expect the values of `a`, `b`, `c` to be changed, but they're not:

```
>> print reduce [a b c]   
10 20 30
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> set varnames: [a b c] [10 20 30]
== [10 20 30]

>> foreach i varnames [set i 0]
== 0

>> reduce varnames
== [0 0 0]
```

You've given i a value from the loop, and then given it a different value of 0, but you actually haven't altered the word that i referred to.  `set` allows you to do this.

Comment: Yes, it works. I think set should be emphasized more than ':' assignment.

Comment: Do you need colon in  `set varnames: [a b c] [10 20 30]` ?

Comment: @rnso no; `set varnames [a b c] [10 20 30]` is fine

Comment: @Geeky, this can't work. Try it in a new console and you will see why not. It needs at least two operation, first **set 'varnames [a b c]**

Comment: or in one line **set set 'varnames [a b c] [10 30 40]**

Comment: @sqlab you're right, I assumed `varnames` was already defined before

Comment: Even if **varnames** is already defined, it will not work, as varnames is set to **[a b c]** and then **[10 20 30]** is left alone

Answer (score 2):

one more, but shortest solution

```
>> set [a b c] 0
== 0
>> reduce [a b c]
== [0 0 0]
```

one more

```
set set 'varnames [a b c] [0]
>> print probe varnames
[a b c]
0 0 0
```

Comment: Question and answers very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234891/parallel-list-assignment-in-red-language/46235435#46235435

Comment: `set varnames: [a b c] 0`

Comment: of course, but **set set-word:** was shown already by Graham above